# C# - How can I get the JSON response in case of error 400? (HttpRequests)

Tags: c#

Sometimes I get error code 400, for example when I try to login with wrong password. On other API(python) it returns status codes, so how can I get the actual response from the server?

EDIT: my code:
headers.cs:

```cs
public string Postheaders(string url, string data, string deviceID, string deviceID_sig, string userAgent)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers["NDCDEVICEID"] = deviceID;
    request.Headers["NDC-MSG-SIG"] = deviceID_sig;
    request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US";
    request.UserAgent = userAgent;
    request.Host = "service.narvii.com";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(data);
    }
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
    var response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    return response;
}
```

client.cs

```cs
public string Login(string email, string password)
{
    var deviceinfo = new device();
    var headers = new headers();
    string data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
        email = email,
        v = 2,
        secret = string.Format("0 {0}", password),
        deviceID = deviceinfo.deviceID,
        clientType = 100,
        action = "normal",
        timestamp = (long)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds * 1000
    });
    string response = headers.Postheaders(string.Format("{0}/g/s/auth/login", api), data, deviceinfo.deviceID, deviceinfo.deviceID_sig, deviceinfo.userAgent);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: What kind of JSON response are you expecting if there's an error? What exactly are you getting in your python application?

Comment: In the same way as you get the repsonse on status code 200

Comment: {api_statuscode: "204"...} or something like that. And I'm making a C# application. Let me put example of the script into the question

Comment: @itsme86 Have a look at https://api.imgur.com/3/account/ - do you see the response although it is a 401 status code? - it is very common to return more then just the response code

Comment: Rufo, the problem is that .NET doesn't return a status code but an error(which you can avoid with try but still), while it should just return 400. It just errors with a 400. How can I get an statuscode in that case?

Comment: And also I'm trying to POST.

Comment: Just check `webResponse.StatusCode` for an error code. The reason it's throwing an exception is because you're blindly trying to read from the response stream when the request returned an error.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. Add that as an answer meanwhile so I can just approve it tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/CaFBpC

Comment: Sir, how can I use that with headers and sending data though?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(@"{
                    'status': 0, 'code':400, 'message':'bad request'
                    }");
  JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(jobject);
  o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Concat });
  return Request.CreateResponse(o1);
```